# How to efficiently measure multithreaded compile time with g++ on Linux?

Tags: c++, g++, profiling, compiler-optimization, compile-time

I'm currently measuring the compile time of a C++ project with `time`. The `real` field is very helpful because it clearly indicates the time the compilation spends in the real world but the big drawback behind this is that the time spent by the compilation depends on the computer activity (if I'm doing a lot of tasks on the computer the compilation will be slower and vice versa). I read that it could be interesting to measure compile time by adding both `user` and `sys` times but I did several tries and the times measured were a lot different everytime so I don't think this technique is very reliable.

My problem today is that the best way I found to measure compile time is with the `real` field of the `time` command but I don't want to do nothing on the computer during this time just to have an accurate compile time measure since I also need to work.

Does anyone know a good alternative to do this ?

I think it can be even harder to find a good measurement technique because the compilation is multithreaded and so the compile time perceived by the system can be very high while it's much lower.

Thx!

Comment: what do you actually care about? The time spend by your CPU(s)? Or the time you have to wait?

Comment: I want to measure accurately the time the CPU spends compiling and if it's possible run other heavy programs on the computer at the same time.

Comment: @Tesla123 Its mostly not possible, because there are many indirect ways the programms influence each other except sharing CPU cycles, namly caches, memory bandwidth, disk bandwidth, power budget to list a few.

Comment: If you want to know how much wall-clock time a compile would take on an otherwise-idle computer, there's no good substitute for that except leaving your computer idle.  If you're ok with knowing something else, like total *CPU* time spent (e.g. 8 CPU-seconds per second on an 8-core CPU), or actual wall-time spent when sharing the CPU with whatever else you were doing, you can measure those.